# Invalid URI: The URI is empty while consuming the web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I have added a webservice in my project, with the help of this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx

I have made by url dynamic by following the steps of this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic

but the problem is I don't have the URI in my reference.cs. Also I don't have web.config file.

It gives the following error when I run my client:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
at OCC_Client.pivClassTestClient.pivClassWebService.set_Url(String value) in
at OCC_Client.pivClassTestClient.pivClassWebService..ctor() in C:\Workspace\O
at OCC_Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Workspace\OCC_Client\OCC_Client
```

It points to this section of the code in the refernce.cs file

```
public new string Url {
        get {
            return base.Url;
        }
        set {
            if ((((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(base.Url) == true) 
                        && (this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly == false)) 
                        && (this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(value) == false))) {
                base.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            }
            base.Url = value;
        }
    }
```

Please help. I'm very new to web services.

Comment: The stack trace indicates that the exception is happening in the Main method, please post that code. I suspect you are trying to access the web service without first defining the URL.

Comment: Where do I have to define the URL? I have made it dynamic. Please help

Comment: By making it dynamic it means you can supply it at runtime by whatever means you need, but you do have to supply it before you can call the web service, otherwise how does it know which web service to connect to. To help more we would need to see that code that calls the web service.

Comment: Thinking about it are you saying you don't know where to put the URL because in the article it says add it to your web config but a console application doesn't have a web.config? If so you want to add it to app.config.